# iOS How to edit(update) date i table view cell parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

How i can to edit or update data i data base use parse.
How to delete date from cell i know, code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {     
if editingStyle == .delete {
                        // Delete the row from the data source
                        let query = PFQuery(className: "requests")
                        let currReceipt = self.data[indexPath.row]
                        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: currReceipt.objectId!)
                        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                self.alert(message: "We could not delete the receipt", title: "Oops! Something went wrong number 1!")
                            }else{
                                for object in objects!{
                                    self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                    object.deleteInBackground()
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    self.alert(message: "Successfully delete from open task list", title: "Task done")
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    } 
}
```

Can i use same function to update data for each cell?
So i want something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "requests")
    let currReceipt = self.data[indexPath.row]
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: currReceipt.objectId!)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
    if error != nil {
          self.alert(message: "We could not delete the receipt", title: "Oops! Something went wrong number 1!")
    }
    else {            
       //UPDATE OBJECT
       object["agestart"] = self.fromAge.text
       object["ageend"] = self.toAge.text
       object["location"] = self.location.text
       object.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in 
           if error != nil {
               self.alert(message: "Error while updating object", title: "Oops! Something went wrong number 1!")
           }
           else {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
           })
          }
}
```

Comment: @Andrew, but as I see that, your question code have delete code.

Comment: I ask how to edit data, use same principle like delete date

Answer (score 1):

Try This custome swipe:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
    }

    let update = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Update") { (action, indexPath) in
        // update item at indexPath
    }

    update.backgroundColor = UIColor.grey

    return [delete, update]
}
```